# Add analyzer to a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type named `placess` as follows:

```
 "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
```

I have created an analyzer as follows:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/ashojash/_settings' -d '{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter": { 
                "type":     "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type":      "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "autocomplete_filter" 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
'
My question is that how can I add this analyzer to an existing field named `name`?

I tried

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/ashojash/_mapping/venues' -d '
{
"venues" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            type:"string",
            "analyzer": "persian"
            }
    }
 }
}'
```

But this gives me conflict field [name] already exists.
how can I add this analyzer to an existing field named `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this at the same time when you create your index (you cannot change an analyzer to a field after its creation):

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/ashojash' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "venues": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Sorry new to elasticSearch, Can I specify an analyzer when querying the data?

Comment: You can specify analyzers for index time and search time. It depends on what you want to achieve. You need to explain your use case in more details.

Comment: Actually I have mysql database which gets synced with elastic search (those fields which I want to perform search on).  
In the name field of ``venues`` I want to have a suggester with ``edge_ngram`` (I also apply more analyzers like persian ,etc.) 
and I want to apply those analyzers on specefic fields.  
That's all I can think of which may be important.  
If any more info needed tell me. Thanks

Comment: Ok, then you need to do this at index creation time, like I suggested. Then only you can start syncing your DB.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you don't need to specify ``_settings`` when creating index (As you have in the answer)